# "Show Applications" how to see more apps per line without using a GNOME extension? (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: gnome-shell, appmenu

By playing around with the settings in gnome-shell.css (under the section "App Vault/Grid") I can get more lines of icons to display on the "Show Applications" screen,  but how can I get more rows to display?  My goal is to make better use of the screen by having more app icons on the screen even if the icons are smaller.

I realize the proper way to edit gnome-shell.css is to make a custom theme, but until I get my hands around my main goal, I am editing /usr/share/gnome-session/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css directly and using Alt-F2-r to see the results of my changes.

Comment: Columns and rows has the same solution? @pomsky (skipped review for the moment)

Comment: @Fabby Ah, yes, right! Retracted. I guess I got thrown off by the title ("*more apps per line*"), sorry 'bout that :(